Analyze YOY data using NRQL
I wanted to analyze the year on year or bi-yearly growth of the metrices stored in New relic using NRQL queries. I am trying something like below, but not getting desired result.
select  (max(`storageBytes.Maximum`)/1024/1024/1024) as 'Storage (GB)'  FROM AzureSqlDatabaseData where displayName = 'MyDatabase' and monthOf(timestamp)='January 2024' FACET  monthOf(timestamp),displayName UNTIL  6 months ago COMPARE WITH 1 hour ago

I have tried the query given above and expecting a comparison preferably in a table format with 2 columns. First one provides the value 1 year/6 months before and other one the current value.
Can anyone help me figuring out the correct query for this.
Thanks for the help.
